# Installing guiffy on Ubuntu

Tags: installation

I chose Linux X86 from this page: http://www.guiffy.com/download/download.html

Upon running the installation script, I got this error:

```
The installer cannot run in this UI mode. To specify the interface mode, use the -i command-line option, followed by the UI mode identifier. The valid UI modes identifiers are GUI, Console, and Silent.
```

Running the script with `-i GUI`, `-i Console`, or -`i Silent` does not help either.

How do I workaround this?

Comment: Did you try the "Linux (Any Architecture)" package?

Comment: Yes, did that and it worked

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I have newer jdk in my system, so I downloaded and installed "any architecture" package (instead of X86) successfully.